# XSLT how to check if the current node has any attribute or not

Tags: xslt

I have xml files which are dynamic. There are many elements and some may have attributes or may not have. This is defined in the xsd file.

I am using the recursive method(for-each) to display the node contents one by one. But if any tag has any attribute then the condition does not match and that tag's contents are not displayed.

I want to check if current element has any attribute or not. If has then also display the contents otherwise also display the tag's contents.

Piece of code of my xslt:

```
<xsl:template match="node()" mode="chapter">
    <xsl:for-each select="node()">
       <xsl:if test="current()[name() = 'CHAPTER']">
          <fo:block>
             <xsl:apply-templates select="current()[name() = 'CHAPTER']" mode="chapter" />
          </fo:block>
      </xsl:if>
   </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>
```

In the above code, in one of xml inputs, CHAPTER tag has an attribute. Hence the if condition becomes false and it does not enter the if block though the current node is CHAPTER.

I want to check if CHAPTER has any attribute or not.
Please suggest.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you could add another predicate in your condition, such as:

```
<xsl:if test="name() = 'CHAPTER' and not(@*)">
```

this will not process `CHAPTER` nodes with attributes.

Comment: Hi Adam and Joel. Thank you so much for your answers. This is working only for some specific places. But now when I debugged my code, I see that current() method is not returning any value. Can you please tell me what is the problem? Because of this reason, the conditions are becoming false and it is not entering my apply template block. Please help me.

Comment: Ok. But what could be the alternative for it? node() also does not seem to be working at this moment. And I cannot hardcode the element names like CHAPTER/TITLE/etc. Because there can be any tag under CHAPTER and I have to display the contents. SO I am using recursion to call Tag within another and so on. Please suggest.

Comment: instead of `<xsl:for-each select="node()">`, do `<xsl:for-each select="*">` instead.

Answer (score 1):

Your code looks a bit overly complicated to me. You have a template that matches any node, and then a loop over every child node, which you then test to see if it is a `CHAPTER`, you then seem to apply other templates on that `CHAPTER`. As such your template does not really do anything particularly useful, and it is hard to follow the business logic.

I think you should look to write this in a mode identity transform style manner, where you can create templates to just process the parts you are interested in or throw away the parts you are not interested in. By doing such a thing, your template above might look more like:

```
<xsl:template match="CHAPTER">
    <fo:block>
        <!-- anything else related specifically to CHAPTER element here -->

        <!-- process children of chapter using other templates... -->
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </fo:block>
</xsl:template>
```

If you wanted to only process `CHAPTER` elements without attributes you could use:

```
<xsl:template match="CHAPTER[not(@*)]">
    <fo:block>
        <!-- anything else related specifically to CHAPTER element here -->

        <!-- process children of chapter using other templates... -->
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </fo:block>
</xsl:template>
```

In the above template you would handle the processing of all things that are directly related to CHAPTER and then you would define sub-templates for handling other elements/nodes that you are interested in. This breaks your code up into nice simple parts, for example:

```
<xsl:template match="CHAPTER[not(@*)]">
    <fo:block>
        <!-- anything else related specifically to CHAPTER element here -->

        <!-- process children of CHAPTER element using other templates... -->
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </fo:block>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="TITLE">
   <fo:block font-size="18pt" font-family="sans-serif">
     <xsl:copy-of select="text()"/>
   </fo:block>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="SYNOPSIS">
    <!-- we are not interested in the SYNOPSIS, so do nothing! -->
<xsl:template>

<!-- identity transform driver -->
<xsl:template match="node() | @*">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="node() | @*"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

In the above I have imagined that your `CHAPTER` elements may also have `TITLE` child element and that you may want to output those in another `fo:block` as well. I have also imagined that your `CHAPTER` elements may have a `SYNOPSIS` child element which you want to ignore and not produce any output for.

You can also find plenty of other examples of this style of XSLT coding by Googling for XSLT identity transforms.